# transform data from list of tuples to df

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have list of tuples which contains info about comment (string text) and date when comment was posted. For example:

```
comments[1]

(datetime.date(2016, 8, 29),
 'I played with these ATM before but they are just too expensive way to buy bitcoins.There were a few in the city I live but many of them already stop operation, most likely because no one actually uses them.')
```

I have function `lda_description` which return list of tuples `(topic, value)`, `topic` is number from 1 and 40 and returned list length also is from 1 and 40 for example:

```
lda_description(comments[1][1])

[(10, 0.43287377217078077), (14, 0.43712141484779793), (21, 0.068338146314754045)]
```

Problem is that I want `lda_description` results map to pandas dataframe which have 40 columns of topics and index is datetime. The dataframe field value should be a sum of all comments' `lda_description` of each topic at specific date.

I have the solution which in my opinion is not efficient and maybe someone can help me at this :)

```
#Creating empty dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(0, index=pd.date_range(datetime.datetime(2013,12,1), datetime.datetime(2016,11,21)).tolist(),
                  columns=range(1,41))
df["count"] = 0

i = 0
for com in comments:

    if i % 50000 == 0:
        print(datetime.datetime.now(), i)
    i += 1

    topic_dist = lda_description(com[1])

    for dist in topic_dist:

        df.set_value(com[0],dist[0],
                     df.ix[com[0]][dist[0]] + dist[1])
        df.set_value(com[0],'count',
                     df.ix[com[0]]['count'] + 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest getting your LDA values together first, and then constructing a data frame with the data already prepared.  For example:

```
# sample data
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
n = 40
dates = pd.date_range("2013-12-01", "2016-11-21")
corpus = np.repeat("foo", len(dates))

# toy function, outputs (<topic number>, <topic-membership proba>) tuples
def lda_description(doc, n):
    return list(zip(np.arange(n), np.random.random(size=n)))

# each element of data has the LDA topic-membership probability for n=40 topics
data = [[lda[1] for lda in lda_description(doc, n)] for doc in corpus]
```

Now just construct the data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=dates, columns=range(1,n+1))

df.head()
                  1         2         3              39        40         
2013-12-01  0.756845  0.741939  0.334812  ...  0.383386  0.687347
2013-12-02  0.013250  0.143308  0.025458  ...  0.413655  0.581954   
2013-12-03  0.464378  0.889262  0.208653  ...  0.885814  0.685987   
2013-12-04  0.816939  0.613601  0.958807  ...  0.761439  0.758965   
2013-12-05  0.856021  0.191507  0.956722  ...  0.869742  0.543119
```

If your `count` column is just meant to keep a serial index of the rows, create that column with:

```
df.assign(count=range(len(dates)))
```